# How to display progress drawable animation in Chip Material Component?

Tags: android, material-design, android-architecture-components, material-components, android-chips

According to the official [Design docs for Action Chips](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html#action-chips), we are supposed to be able to add a progress state to chips. Sadly, the [Development docs](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/) don't mention this at all. Has anyone managed to figure out how to achieve the effect shown [here](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-design%2Fassets%2F1OpzE0nXqZJBm66WRVbaGvTbZEIaRAWfD%2Faction-chip-behavior-confirmation.mp4)?

Comment: From what I have seen this is not possible with the current material library

Comment: @tyczj now it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to implement this behavior using the `chipIcon` attribute and `androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.CircularProgressDrawable`.

xml

```
app:chipIconWithProgress="@{viewModel.taskIsStarting ? null : @drawable/ic_play_arrow}"
```

and BindingAdapter

```
@BindingAdapter("chipIconWithProgress")

fun Chip.setChipIconWithProgress(item: Drawable?) {   
  chipIcon = item
    ?: CircularProgressDrawable(context!!).apply {
      setStyle(CircularProgressDrawable.DEFAULT)
      start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution. Works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Material Components Library and the `Chip` component.

In your layout use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.chip.Chip
        android:id="@+id/chip"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Chip.Action"
        app:iconStartPadding="2dp"
        ../>
```

Then use as `chipIcon` a `ProgressIndicator` provided by the library:

```
   ProgressIndicatorSpec progressIndicatorSpec = new ProgressIndicatorSpec();
    progressIndicatorSpec.loadFromAttributes(
            this,
            null,
            R.style.Widget_MaterialComponents_ProgressIndicator_Circular_Indeterminate);
    progressIndicatorSpec.circularInset = 1; // Inset.
    progressIndicatorSpec.circularRadius =
            (int) dpToPx(this, 8); // Circular radius is 8 dp.
    IndeterminateDrawable progressIndicatorDrawable =
            new IndeterminateDrawable(
                    this,
                    progressIndicatorSpec,
                    new CircularDrawingDelegate(),
                    new CircularIndeterminateAnimatorDelegate());


    Chip chip = findViewById(R.id.chip);
    chip.setChipIcon(progressIndicatorDrawable);
```

with this util method:

```
public static float dpToPx(@NonNull Context context, @Dimension(unit = Dimension.DP) int dp) {
    Resources r = context.getResources();
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, r.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

[image]

You can customize the colors and all other attributes:

```
progressIndicatorSpec.indicatorColors = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.progress_colors);
progressIndicatorSpec.growMode = GROW_MODE_OUTGOING;
```

[image]

**Note:** this requires at least the version **`1.3.0-alpha02`**.