# Is there a way to somehow implement Action Chips in android with a progress icon?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-chips

I was looking for a way to implement an action chip with a progress icon, as shown [here](https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/bf49ecb84b34a2a88e2765c597261ffd893a7fcff1eed4cd688b9db7eca33337be773c034bfe35feb48c74bd4d62a2db4a5dc70a0ebd8002cb29a4c295e0dc03) in the [material component guidelines](https://material.io/components/chips#action-chips). There seems to be no documentation regarding it. Someone had asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54536053/how-to-display-progress-drawable-animation-in-chip-material-component), but the answer provided isn't any recognized attribute for the chip component, nor does the method of the Chip class exist.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You may add a material component guidelines link to give more insight to others and help them to have more information to given an accurate answer

Comment: Thanks, did that!